# How to return the sum of a row - INDEX appears not to "rotate"

Tags: excel, indexing

Excel problem.  Imagine a simple matrix M, say 8r x 10c.  Suppose that 1c contains some search criteria.  I now wish to return the sum of of all the numbers in 5-8c of every row in which 1c matches 10. Suppose C=INDEX(M,0,1) and V={0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0} then conceptually I should be able to write =SUMPRODUCT((C=10)*SUMPRODUCT(INDEX(M,ROW(M),0),V)).

I cannot get it to work.  C is a vertical vector {0;1; ...} and therefore should induce the first SUMPRODUCT to loop over the rows such that a different row is ripped out of M with every iteration, as works with eg the trickery of SUMPRODUCT((C=10)*ROW(M)).

But when INDEX is involved, it simply fails to work.

I noticed something else that does not make much sense.  I can write
=SUM(INDEX(M,ROW(M),0)).  It returns the sum of the first row.  I can copy this same formula as an array formula and suddenly I find to the sum of each row.  Great (-ish).  In theory, I should therefore be able to write =SUMPRODUCT(SUM(INDEX(M,ROW(M),0))) to get the sum of the sums.  But it fails again.  Same problem as above.

Any suggestion much appreciated.  Thanks.

PS: In reality V is dynamically computed based on some column criteria.

Comment: A mock up of the data would help us visualize this better.

Comment: Hm ... 8x10 is 80 cells.  Fill them, counting from 0 to 79.  M(2,1) will then be 10 and the formula should thus return M(2,5) + ...  + M(2,8), which would be 14 + ... + 17 = 62.  Makes sense?

Comment: Nope.  how and where are the inputs defining the range?  Do you want the whole array? Row? Column? A specific range?  Do you put 2,5 in one cell and 2,8 in another to denote what range you want added up? or, do you want to put in 10 and get a sum of that entire row not including the 10 or is ten included in the sum?

Comment: I'm sorry?  M(2,5) refers to the cell in row 2, column 5 of table M.  If you filled the table from start to finish as I suggested, that cell will be 14.  I might add that In this simple case, it is possible to write SUMPRODUCT(INDEX(M,SUMPRODUCT((C=10)*ROW(M)),0),V).  Unfortunately, this formula breaks down when more than one cell in C equals 10.

Comment: That's the thing, what is C,V and M are they named ranges? Are they columns?

Comment: Scott - I appreciate you engaging with my problem but may I suggest that you re-read the OP?  Yes, C, V and M are (or could be) "named" ranges.  They are completely and unambiguously defined in the OP.  To the point where you could paste my definition into Excel.